# "this" is not working with .find() in a .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access an object using `this` inside an `.each()` and want to perform `.find()` with it but in console it says `.find` is undefined function.

```
data=$(data);
$("tr", data).each(function(){
    var est = this.find(".estname a").html;
});
```

I have also tried this:

```
data=$(data);
$("tr", data).each(function(){
    var est = $(this).find(".estname a").html;
});
```

In console it shows `function()` instead of any object :(

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Always read the document before asking a question, or else this will show that you have not done any research on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be:

```
var est = $(this).find(".estname a").html();
```

With parentheses after `html` function.

Comment: congratz with 100, and probably a badge: +1